# Getting ImportError after setting up Flask application factory

Tags: python, flask, routes, factory

I am making a basic blog website with Flask. I have tried to stick to the best recommended practice as mentioned in official documentation. I want to understand why after adding application factory and making subsequent changes in modules and application strucutre, I am getting **ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app'**

Application structure:

```
project:.
|   .env
|   .gitignore
|   config.py
|   requirements.txt
|   server.py           
+---app
|   |   forms.py
|   |   routes.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---static
|   |   +---images
|   |   |       ...
|   |   |       
|   |   +---js
|   |   |       index.js
|   |   |       
|   |   \---styles
|   |           ...
|   |           
|   +---templates
|   |   |   ...
|   |   |   
|   |   \---macros
|   |           ...
```

Here's the code:

**`__init__.py`**

```
from flask import Flask


def init_app():
    """Initialize the core app"""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object("config.Config")

    with app.app_context():
        from . import routes
        return app
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from app import app                     #I am getting ImportError here
from app.forms import ContactForm


@app.route("/")
def index():
    title = "Welcome to Project"
    return render_template("hero-page.html", title=title)


@app.route("/gallery/")
def gallery():
    return render_template("gallery.html")


@app.route("/about-us/")
def about_us():
    return render_template("about-us.html")
```

**config.py**

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, ".env"))


class Config:
    """Set Flask environment variables"""

    ENVIRONMENT = environ.get("ENVIRONMENT")
    FLASK_APP = environ.get("FLASK_APP")
    FLASK_DEBUG = environ.get("FLASK_DEBUG")
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
```

What should I add/modify to resolve this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following line in routes.py from
`from app import app` to `from flask import current_app as app`. This solved the circular import error

Answer (score 0):

It seem like there has no **app.py** in app directory.

you should create a app.py file

or should use **from app import init_app as app**

Comment: But I am returning app object from `__init__.py` which means the app directory becomes a package.

Comment: then you should use **from app import init_app as app**